# Raster to Vector using GDAL without dissolving vector data on like-features

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vector-tiles, polygonize

Python beginner here. I am converting a raster to a vector in shapefile format. I am successful in doing this but my output isn't quite what I'm looking for. I need the output to have a "square" pixel for each attribute/row of data. My output currently is merging and dissolving like features that are connecting. Instead, each pixel needs its own row of data. I am not sure if this is do-able with GDAL and how I currently have my code set-up. Here's my code:

```
ClipRas_raster = gdal.Open(r'path to my raster I'm converting')
band = ClipRas_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
band.ReadAsArray()
proj = ClipRas_raster.GetProjection()
WGS84_proj = osr.SpatialReference()
WGS84_proj.ImportFromWkt(proj)

GP_POP = 'path to my output shapefile'
call_drive = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
create_shp = call_drive.CreateDataSource(GP_POP)
shp_layer = create_shp.CreateLayer('layername', srs = WGS84_proj)
new_field = ogr.FieldDefn(str('ID'), ogr.OFTInteger)
shp_layer.CreateField(new_field)
gdal.Polygonize(band, None, shp_layer, 0, [], callback = None)
create_shp.Destroy()
ClipRas_raster = None
```

**Current Output**:
[image]
**Desired Output (Difficult to tell here, but each pixel is a square polygon**:
[image]
Any suggestions? Can I make this a function so I can use again?

Answer (score 0):

GDAL does not have function for converting pixels into polygons. QGIS does have such a function named "Raster pixels to polygons"

> Raster pixels to polygons
>
> This algorithm converts a raster layer to a vector layer, by creating
> polygon features for each individual pixel's extent in the raster
> layer.
>
> Any nodata pixels are skipped in the output.